# Weighted sampling in R problems

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YQt.png)

I want to do weighted sampling in R, with original data imbalanced between 0 and 1, I used **sample** to do but result in still biased data.

```
nsample=4000
model_weights <- ifelse(train$Bankrupt == 1,0.9677419,0.03225806)
samp_idx <- sample(4107, nsample, replace=T, prob=model_weights)
data.weighted <- data[samp_idx, ]
table(data.weighted$Bankrupt)

0    1 
3761  239
```

Comment: please provide some data to make this a reproducible example. I assume you want to `sample` from `train` not from `data` or compute `samp_idx` from `data` instead from `train`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the stratified function.  You want to do something like this, but it is impossible to tell from the data you provide.

```
stratified(DF, "Status", c(Bankrupt = 30, NotBankrupt = 1))
```

The column in the data holding the groups should be character and the groups should match those in your list of weights you pass to the stratified function.